# Trying to set up Discourse in a VM but Ruby can't find Gemfile

Tags: ruby, virtualbox, vagrant, discourse

I am trying to set up [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) following the Vagrant instructions on Github. I'm on a Windows machine, so I downloaded the VM and started it, then I used putty to ssh in and try to start setting up Discourse. When I type `bundle install` I get a message that says `Bundler::GemfileNotFound`. Where do I go from here?

Comment: You need to `cd` to dir where discourse is, prior to running `bundle install`.

Comment: The VM has no directories, so I can cd nowhere. And it seems obvious that you don't mean the discourse directory on my physical machine, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Really, there are no directories? Bizarre. Sorry, haven't tried discourse vm myself, but I was hoping that you made this trivial mistake :)

Comment: Yeah, I type dir and all it shows is "postinstall.sh", I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: When I ssh into vagrant using Putty, I end up at vagrant@precise32. I think I should be at vagrant@discourse-0.8.4 but I don't know how to get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant mounts the Discourse sources to `/vagrant`. When you run `vagrant ssh` (or use Putty to ssh into the VM) you'll be in the home directory of the vagrant user (where the `postinstall.sh` file is). So just type `cd /vagrant` and you can continue. I'm not sure whether they just omitted this in their readme or if you normally would end up in `/vagrant` and something went wrong. I tested it and also endet up in `/home/vagrant`, like you.

Note: the `@precise32` is the hostname of the VM, not the directory (`~`).

Comment: Thanks. Typing cd /vagrant worked. I'm not sure if I followed your explanation of where I was though; was I in a parent, child, or sibling directory when I started?

Comment: You were in `/home/vagrant`, the home directory of the vagrant user (_roughly_ a sibling).

Comment: So, I start in /home/vagrant then type cd /vagrant, and then where am I?

Comment: Then you're in `/vagrant` - paths with a leading `/` are absolute paths (starting from `/`, no matter where you are).